# set() with element-counters (like sort | unique -c in bash)

Tags: python, duplicates, set, counter

In python, if I have

```
A=[3,3,1,8,2,5,8,2,2]
```

and I do

```
set(A)
```

I get

```
{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}
```

i.e. a set with A's elements without duplicates

Is there a fast way to also have counters to know how many instances of every number I have in A?

Something like:

```
{[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1], [8, 2]}
```

Or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: Use a dictionary where you increment the value each time you add an element.

Comment: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: As @Kevin said, use `collections.Counter`. Something like: `result = collections.Counter(A)`. Then, you can iterate over it using `for value, count in result.items():` to obtain the value and counts respectively.

Comment: This is a clear dupe, but I hope the question is not deleted since people coming from shell scripting/command-line may well ask it exactly in this way, so it could be a useful waypoint